# can not resolve 'updateUI' firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to authenticate users with email and password through firebase. But it shows can not resolve updateUI(user).
Here's this part of the code.

```
public void OnContinue(View view) {
    if(hasClickedCountinueOnce){
        EditText emailTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        String user = userNAAME.getText().toString();
        String passwordText = password.getText().toString();
        String email = emailTextBox.getText().toString();
        //todo manage new account here
        if(!user.isEmpty() && !passwordText.isEmpty() ){
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordText)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d("SignInFailed", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                updateUI(user);
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Log.w("SignInFailed", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(SignUP.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                updateUI(null);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `updateUI(null)` is a method which updates the screen layout according to the authentication results. I think you have directly copied the code from developer blogs. You have to find out the actual code inside of  that method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is from the [Firebase Quickstart-Android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L186-L201) project. This is what it does. You can implement something similar:

```
   private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh, i get it now. Thanks, I previously thought it was some kind of method under the firebase user class.

Comment: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697262/cannot-resolve-method-updateui), this is actually an oversight in Google's documentation. From what I've experienced, this type of thing happens fairly often, making learning harder.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your problem rightly with the limited code that u shared above, the function call "updateUI" refred here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) is the call/function you have to write on your own to update ur UI elements, and as @BobSnyder mentioned here's the link to a reference code (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L209)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own custom UpdateUI method in your MainActivity and write the code for what your app should do when a user is logged in with a condition for example `if(user!=null).`

Answer (score 0):

Your coding for authentication is working.

What is the purpose of **FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();** inside successful login ?

To get current user, you have to implement **Auth Change Listner**  after success login as,

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user !=null){
                   updateUI(user);
                }
            }
        };


mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```

(Use different variable name)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateUI(@Nullable GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        if (account != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, account.getDisplayName()));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to explain what exactly this code does and how it solves the problem.