# Cannot resolve method updateUI()

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to add a google login with firebase to my project, following the offical documentation for google sign-in.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

I already seen other questions but no one can resolve my problem. I don't understand if I have to create my own updateUI() method or I have to add some libraries, and if I have to write it, what I have to do. The code is short and simply

```
package com.database.gabriele.databasefb;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SignInButton button;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        button = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        updateUI(account);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code, it return me the error "Cannot resolve method updateUI(...)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you don't have this method in your class, you need to create it according to your needs. The documentation only mentioned that you need to do some UI updates when the application starts.

**For example,** check if the user already logged in or not and do something accordingly :

```
//Change UI according to user data.
public void updateUI(FirebaseUser account){

    if(account != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"You Signed In successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class));

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"You Didnt signed in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this. As @uberphoebe points out, and as I've seen in other places, Google's own documentation for stuff like this looks and feels incomplete. That makes it much harder for people who are learning, such as myself currently.

Answer (score 2):

Its an interesting question you pose and leaves you hanging if you read the documentation. 
Lets say you want to anonymously register user using your app. You could use this code

```
   final  FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                            String user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().toString();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
```

so this line

```
String user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().toString();
```

will give you the string returned for the current user.

You can now pass this to the  method updateUI(user) and do what you want with it.
1. See whether there is a value
2. Log the value
3. etc etc
To do this you need to write the method

```
    updateUI(String user)
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, user+" <- this is the user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I know this is a simple example. I always search for simple examples not for the complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

`UpdaeUI()` method is just for updating user interface with user's current authentication state like user is already signed in or not if user is already signed in then it redirects user to the dashboard activity screen otherwise on login screen.

When i was doing this i had same question, to make this easy i created an application only for user authentication using firebase. you can see my code on github using below link. I hope this may help you to understand.

https://github.com/Vijay-Tahelramani/Android_Firebase_Authentication

It will allow you to create login, signup, forget and change password, auto sign-out functions. it also allows you to send user name and profile image.